# Json pass various fliends on json array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this code that fetches some fields from MYSQL database. The problem is that the php appears plain white. But if I delete elements of while and leave only one `,` the array prints fine.

```
$sql = "SELECT rest.img,rest.rest_name,horario.desc_hor, rest.descp, rest.rest_id FROM rest, type, horario WHERE rest.type_id = type.type_id AND rest.id_hor = horario.id_hor AND rest.type_id=1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$cnt = $result->num_rows;
$json = array();


if($cnt>0){
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $json['']=$row['img'];
    $json['']=$row['rest_name'];
    $json['']=$row['desc_hor'];
    $json['']=$row['descp'];
    $json['']=$row['rest_id'];
    }
}
print( json_encode($json));
```

Comment: What's with the `$json['']=` I guess you wanted to write `$json[]=`.

Comment: Yes. I tried naming the collumn of the array

Comment: Note that you are breaking up your data in different rows so that you will not be able to relate anything to anything. You should use something like `$json[] = $row;` or `$json[$row['rest_id']] = $row;` instead.

Comment: "fliends" -- that's a new one. I approve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are not assigning indexes automatically. You are always assigning the index `['']` for all columns and rows in the array.

Try this...

```
$json = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    array_push($json, $row);
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

or this...

```
$json = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $json[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Of either ways, will generate the automátic indexes in the array.